# LTSP fails while downloading images

Tags: debian, tftp, ltsp

Some time ago, I've configured LTSP on Debian machine.
I've been using it from time to time and it worked.

Today it stopped working and I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Client says:

```
Intel UNDI, PXE-2.1 
PXE Software Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation 
Copyright (C) 2010 Oracle Corporation 

CLIENT MAC ADDR: 08 00 27 06 AB AB GUID: 8E607128-4C80-4960-BF72-347FDBDB27B5 
CLIEHT IP: 192.168.1.163 MASK: 255.255.255.0 DHCP IP: 192.168.1.1 
GATEWAY IP: 192.168.1.1
PXE-E35: TFTP read timeout 
PXE-E39: TFTP cannot read from connection 
PXE-MOF: Exiting Intel PXE ROM. 
FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.
```

I took a look at server's log, but tftp's logs doesn't seem to be useful:

```
Dec  7 22:44:25 Serwer in.tftpd[4568]: RRQ from 192.168.1.163 filename /ltsp/i386/pxelinux.0
Dec  7 22:44:25 Serwer in.tftpd[4568]: tftp: client does not accept options
Dec  7 22:44:25 Serwer in.tftpd[4569]: RRQ from 192.168.1.163 filename /ltsp/i386/pxelinux.0
```

(those messages above are generated by tftp with --verbose mode).

So it looks like I've a connection from tftp clients to server, but why did it die?

I could not find any way to see more log informations.